# how to find out when the code reads parent or child process and how do they communicate in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, linux-kernel

I have a shell program where a fork is created and then used two if else statements to separate the parent and the child process.

My sample program is here and i got a few questions

```
while(true)
{
    /* read command line input */

    x = fork();

    if( x > 0)
        {
         wait(&status);      
        }
    else
        {
         /* run the exec() command  */
        }
}
```

from the above code which statement would it execute first after fork and how would parent know that child exec command was executed successfully or unsuccessfully
 and when would the parent stop to wait and  in which condition and how.
And also how would the wait(&status) code work.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "how to find out" - by formatting the code, in first place. That makes debugging *way more easier.*

Comment: It seems you don't understand `fork`; after it two processes exist and they run *simultaneously*. So asking "which statement is executed first" is really meaningless. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ which has a whole chapter on this.

Comment: Second only to legal clients not telling their lawyers *everything*, it continues to perplex me why people honestly believe trying to *described* their code is an adequate substitution for simply *showing **real** code* in the first place to the very people that, by their own admittance, are supposed to help them understand it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Fork().]

This should give you a better idea of how the fork() system call works.

Comment: `wait(&status)` simply blocks the thread until one of the child processes exit.

Comment: @tangrs, "wait, waitpid - wait for a child process to stop or terminate, The `wait()` function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until status information for one of the terminated child processes of the calling process is avail‐
       able, or until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process."

Answer (score 2):

---

We can't decide which process (parent or child) should execute first.
If a child has already terminated and is a zombie, wait returns immediately with that child's status.
vfork() guarantees that the child runs first, until the child calls exec or exit

Answer (score 1):

According to the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) of `fork`, there is no priority to run the parent or the child process. So, in fact, you cannot expect one to be prior to the other one.

But, if you are using Linux, the child is always scheduled first after the fork. Mainly, because of implementation reasons. Thus, the parent is started after. But, you also have to understand that they run concurrently once they are started. See the [fork manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).